# Primefaces dataTable multiple selection same object

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm having a problem with the dataTable multiple selection with checkbox (like the second one: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf).
When I try to execute a method in my backingBean, the selected items always comes with the right size, but, with the same object. 
Example: I select in my dataTable three Messages: Message 1, Message 2 and Message 3. When I execute my method in the JSF page my selected items comes like this:

```
Messages[0] = Message 1
Messages[1] = Message 1
Messages[2] = Message 1
```

Here is my JSF Page:

```
<p:dataTable id="mensagensLidas" var="msg" value="#{mensagensBean.msgGrupoModel}" 
paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{mensagensBean.selectedMsgsGrupo}">

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%"/>

    <p:column headerText="Titulo:" style="width:49%">  
        #{msg.titulo}  
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="#{msgs.delete}" icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{mensagensBean.excluirMsgsGrupo}" update=":tabMain" ajax="true"/>
    </f:facet>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: why selectionMode="multiple" is in column not in datable as here http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf?

Comment: Edited the question, it's like the second example: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: can you put also code where you print data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. My DataModel was with the getRowData returning always the same object. I was doing a wrong comparison. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Your above code is working fine for me except that I'm using a `rowKey`.
Try using `rowKey` attribute in `p:dataTable`

```
<p:dataTable id="mensagensLidas" var="msg" value="#{mensagensBean.msgGrupoModel}" 
                paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{mensagensBean.selectedMsgsGrupo}"
                rowKey="#{msg.titulo}">
....

</p:dataTable>
```

Using `rowKey` is must and best practice when you have selection in Datables, it helps to map the selected `<tr>` to the POJOs that you're filling up with.
Usually its even better if your `rowKey` is unique propety, you can even put an integer variable in your  `#{msg}` POJO as best practice.

Comment: his examples from primefaces don't use rowKey :/ it uses CarDataModel

Comment: Some times Primefaces Showcase doesn't show full code. You try it with rowKey its perfectly valid.

Comment: I discovered the problem. My DataModel was with the getRowData returning always the same object. I was doing a wrong comparison. Thank you all!